error cargando imagenes obtenidas de whatsapp
estoy haciendo una integracion entre whatsapp y la plataforma glpi. tengo unas funciones para procesar las imagenes y subirlas a la plataforma, ya las funciones estan bien, las probé pasando los parametros explicitos, y funcionan. pero cuando lo integro con whatsapp. para que se suban automaticamente cuando envíen la imagen, no funciona. ya he intentado de todo. he verificado que los datos sin esten asignados antes de llamar a la funcion, he cambiado el flujo del programa. y no doy con el problema:
<?php
    require_once 'whatsapp-glpi.php';
    include 'CelReg.php';
    $config = require 'config.php';
    $usuarios_estado = [];

        function verificarToken($req,$res) {
            try{
                $token = $req['hub_verify_token'];
                $challenge = $req['hub_challenge'];

                if(isset($challenge) && $token == TOKEN_DW){
                    $res->send($challenge);
                }else{
                    $res(400)->send();
                }

            }catch(Exception $e){
                $res(400)->send();
            }
        }

        function recibirMensajes($req,$res) {
            try {
            // *******************************************
                // Analizar bien el $reg, para todos los casos
            $archivo = fopen("log.txt","a");$text = json_encode($req);fwrite($archivo,$text."\r\n"); fclose($archivo);
            // *******************************************
            $obt = $req['object'];  $ent = $req['entry'];   $ent = $ent[0]; $sal = $ent['changes']; $sal = $sal[0]; $sal = $sal['value'];
            // Si es mensaje
            $esmensaje = false; $esenvio = false;
            if(isset($sal['messages'])) {
                $esmensaje = true;
                $mes = $sal['messages'][0];
                $numero = $mes['from'];
                $idmsg = $mes['id'];
                $timestamp = $mes['timestamp'];
                $tipo = $mes['type'];
                $imagen = $mes['image']['id'];
                $audio = $mes['audio']['id'];
                $comentario = $mes['text']['body']; 
            }

            if(isset($sal['contacts'])) {
                    $conta = $sal['contacts'][0];
                $nombre = $conta['profile']['name'];
                $wa_id = $conta['wa_id'];
            }

            if(isset($sal['metadata'])) {
                    $met = $sal['metadata'];
                    $display_phone_number = $met['display_phone_number'];
                    $phone_number_id = $met['phone_number_id'];
            }

            if(isset($sal['statuses'])) {
                $esenvio = true;
                    $est = $sal['statuses'][0];
                    $id_estatus = $est['id'];
                    $st_estatus = $est['status'];
                    $timestap_estatus = $est['timestamp'];
                    $recipiente = $est['recipient_id'];
                    $numero = $recipiente;
                    if(isset( $est['conversation']['id'])) {$conversation_id = $est['conversation']['id'];}
                    if(isset( $est['conversation']['origin']['type'])) {$conversation_origin = $est['conversation']['origin']['type'];}
                    if(isset( $est['pricing']['billable'])) {$pricing = $est['pricing']['billable'];}
                    if(isset( $est['pricing']['pricing_model'])) {$price_model = $est['pricing']['pricing_model'];}
                    if(isset( $est['pricing']['category'])) $price_category = $est['pricing']['category'];
            }

            if (isset($numero) && ($numero == "" || $timestamp == ""))  {
                // Sin info para guardar
            } elseif ($esmensaje) {
                // Hay mensaje  $archivo = fopen("log.txt","a");$texto = json_encode($grabar);  $texto = json_encode($req);$texto = $nombre. "-". $numero ."-". $idmsg ."-". $timestamp ."-". $comentario ."-". $tipo ."\r\n";fwrite($archivo,$texto);
                $sql="Select * from logs Where id_msg ='". $idmsg."' order by estampa_msg DESC limit 1";
                $result = execute($sql);
                //fwrite($archivo,"Paso 0 ".$timestamp. " -> ". $result[0][1] ." <- " .$result[0][4] ."\r\n");
                if(empty($result)) {
                    //fwrite($archivo,"Grabando 0 ".$timestamp. " -> ". $comentario ." <- " .$idmsg ."\r\n");
                    // Llamar a nuevomsg con los datos obtenidos del mensaje
                    $salida = nuevomsg($numero, $idmsg, $timestamp, $comentario, $tipo, $nombre);

                    if ($esmensaje) {
                        if(isset($imagen)){
                            $usuarios_estado = leerEstado();
                            if($usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso'] = 5){
                                $url = obtenerUrlImagen($imagen);
                                $nit = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['NIT'];
                                $ticket = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['ticket']; 
                                subirDocumentoGlpi($ticket, $url, $numero, $nit);
                            }else{
                                EnviarMensajeWhatasapp("mensaje no válido", $numero);
                            }
                        }elseif($audio){
                            EnviarMensajeWhatasapp($audio, $numero, false, $audio);
                        }else{
                            EnviarMensajeWhatasapp($comentario, $numero);
                        }
                    }else {
                    // }else {
                     // $comentario = "hola";
                     // envioplantilla("tecnico_fuera_horario",$numero);
                     // EnviarMensajeWhatasapp($comentario,$numero);
                    if ($timestamp > $result[0][1]) {
                        $salida = actualizatime($result[0][0],$timestamp);
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($esenvio) {

            }
            echo json_encode(['message' => 'EVENT_RECEIVED']);
            exit();
        }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo json_encode(['message' => 'EVENT_RECEIVED']);
            exit();
            }
        }

        function EnviarMensajeWhatasapp($comentario, $numero, $imagen = false, $audio = false) {
            global $config;
            echo $comentario;
            $data=array();
            
            $usuarios_estado = leerEstado();
            
            if(isset($usuarios_estado[$numero])){
                switch($usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso']){
                    case 1:
                        if($comentario === '1'){
                            $usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso'] = 2;
                            $comentario = "ingresa tu nombre completo";
                        }else{
                            $comentario = "opcion invalida";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if(!empty($comentario)){
                            $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['nombre'] = $comentario;
                            $usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso'] = 3;
                            $comentario = "ingresa el NIT sin digito de verificación";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if(!empty($comentario)){
                            $sessionToken = iniciarSesion();
                            $nitValido = buscarEntidad($comentario, $sessionToken);
                            if ($nitValido === null) {
                                $comentario = "el nit ingresado no es valido";
                                cerrarSesion($sessionToken);
                            } else {
                                $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['NIT'] = $comentario;
                                $comentario= "Danos una descripción del problema";
                                $usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso'] = 4;
                                cerrarSesion($sessionToken);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if(!empty($comentario) && !isset($usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['ticket'])){
                            $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['descripcion'] = $comentario;
                            $nit = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['NIT'];

                            $descripcion = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['descripcion'];
                            $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['ticket'] = integracionGlpi($numero, $nit, $descripcion);
                            $usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso'] = 5;
                            $comentario = "Tu solicitud fue registrada, te estaremos informando";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if($imagen){
                            $url = obtenerUrlImagen($comentario);
                            $ticket = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['ticket'];
                            $nit = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['NIT'];
                            subirDocumentoGlpi($ticket, $url, $numero, $nit);
                            $comentario = "";
                        } elseif($audio) {
                            $url = obtenerUrlImagen($comentario);
                            $id_ticket = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['ticket'];
                            $documento = subirDocumentoGlpi($id_ticket, $url, $numero, $nit, true);
                            $comentario = "";
                        }elseif(!empty($comentario) && !$imagen && !$audio) {
                            $id_ticket = $usuarios_estado[$numero]['datos']['ticket'];
                            integracionGlpiFollowups($id_ticket, $comentario);
                            $comentario = "";
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                $comentario = "Bienvenido a la linea de soporte de Dataware Sistemas. selecciona una opcion:\n\n1.solicitud de soporte";
                $usuarios_estado[$numero]['paso'] = 1;
            }
            guardarEstado($usuarios_estado);
            $comentario = "";

            $data = json_encode([
                "messaging_product"=> "whatsapp",
                "recipient_type" => "individual",
                "to" => $numero,
                "type" => "text",
                "text" => [
                    "preview_url" => true,
                    "body" => $comentario
                ]
            ]);

            // if($comentario && !$usuarios_estado[$numero]) {
            // }else{
            //  $data = json_encode([
            //      "messaging_product"=> "whatsapp",
            //      "recipient_type" => "individual",
            //      "to" => $numero,
            //      "type" => "text",
            //      "text" => [
            //          "preview_url" => true,
            //          "body" => $comentario
            //      ]
            //  ]);
            // }
            $token = $config['whatsapp-token'];
            $options = [
                'http' => [
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => [
                        "Content-type: application/json",
                        "Authorization: Bearer $token" 
                    ],
                    'content' => $data,
                    'ignore_errors' => true
                ]
            ];
            $context = stream_context_create($options);
            $response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/$num/messages',false,$context);
            if ($response === false) echo "Error al enviar el mensaje\n"; else echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente\n";
        }
        // Fin Enviar

        function guardarEstado($usuarios_estado) {
            file_put_contents('./estados.json', json_encode($usuarios_estado));
        }

        function leerEstado(){
            if(file_exists('./estados.json')) {
                return json_decode(file_get_contents('estados.json'), true);
            }
            return [];
        }

        function eliminarEstado($numero, &$usuarios_estado) {
            if(isset($usuarios_estado[$numero])) {
                unset($usuarios_estado[$numero]);
                guardarEstado($usuarios_estado);
            }
        }

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $data =json_decode($input, true);
            
            recibirMensajes($data,http_response_code());

        }else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
            if(isset($_GET['hub_mode']) && isset($_GET['hub_verify_token']) && isset($_GET['hub_challenge']) && $_GET['hub_mode'] === 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] === TOKEN_DW){
                    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
            }
        }else{
            http_response_code(403);
        }

<?php
$config = require 'config.php';

function integracionGlpi($num, $nit, $content) {
    global $config;

    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $crearTicketUrl = "https://glpi.url.net/apirest.php/Ticket";
    
    $sessionToken = iniciarSesion();
    if (!$sessionToken) {
        echo "Error iniciando sesión en GLPI";
        return;
    }

    $entidad = buscarEntidad($nit, $sessionToken);
    $usuario = buscarUsuario($num, $sessionToken);

    if ($entidad === null || $usuario === null) {
        echo"no se pudo obtener ID usuario o entidad";
        return;
    }

    $data = [
        "input" => [
            "name" => "Nuevo Ticket",
            "content" => $content,
            "status" => 2,
            "_users_id_requester" => $usuario,
            "entities_id" => $entidad
        ]
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($crearTicketUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken,
        'App-Token: ' . $appToken
    ]);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($res === false) {
        echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $resData = json_decode($res, true);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($resData);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    cerrarSesion($sessionToken);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $resData['id'];
}

function integracionGlpiFollowups($ticket, $content) {
    global $config;
    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $crearFollowUp = "https://glpi.url.net/apirest.php/Ticket/$ticket/ITILFollowup";
    $sessionToken = iniciarSesion($appToken);
    if (!$sessionToken) {
        echo "Error iniciando sesión en GLPI";
        return;
    }
    $data = [
        "input" => [
            "itemtype" => "Ticket",
            "items_id" => $ticket,
            "is_private" => 0,
            "content" => $content
        ]
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($crearFollowUp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken,
        'App-Token: ' . $appToken
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) {
        echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $resData = json_decode($res, true);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($resData);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    cerrarSesion($appToken, $sessionToken);
    curl_close($ch);
}

function iniciarSesion() {
    global $config;
    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $userToken = $config['user-token'];
    $iniciarSesionUrl = "https://glpi.url.net/apirest.php/initSession";
    $ch = curl_init($iniciarSesionUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'App-Token: ' . $appToken,
        'Authorization: ' . $userToken
    ]);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) {
        echo "cURL Error (iniciarSesion): " . curl_error($ch);
        return null;
    } else {
        $sessionData = json_decode($res, true);
        if (isset($sessionData['session_token'])) {
            echo "Sesión creada con éxito";
            return $sessionData['session_token'];
        } else {
            echo "Error en la respuesta de inicio de sesión";
            print_r($sessionData);
            return null;
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

function cerrarSesion($sessionToken) {
    global $config;
    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $cerrarSesionUrl = "https://glpi.url.net/apirest.php/killSession";
    $ch = curl_init($cerrarSesionUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'App-Token: ' . $appToken,
        'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken
    ]);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) {
        echo "Token de sesión inválido";
    } else {
        echo "Sesión finalizada con éxito";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

function buscarUsuario($num, $sessionToken){
    global $config;
    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $buscarEntidadUrl = "https://glpi.url.net/apirest.php/search/User";
    $arrNum = str_split($num);
    unset($arrNum[0], $arrNum[1]);
    $numero = implode('', $arrNum);
    $params = [
            'criteria' =>[
                [
                    'field' => 6,
                    'searchtype' => 'contains',
                    'value' => $numero,
                ]
            ],
            'forcedisplay' => [2]
    ];
    $buscarEntidadUrl .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
    $ch = curl_init($buscarEntidadUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'App-Token: ' . $appToken,
        'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken
    ]);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if($res === false) {
        echo  'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } 
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $data = json_decode($res, true);
    if(!isset($data['data'][0]['2'])){
        echo "no se pudo obtener el id usuario";
        return null;
    }
    $idUsuario = $data['data'][0]['2'];
    echo "\n" . $idUsuario;
    return $idUsuario;
    
}

function buscarEntidad($nit, $sessionToken){
    global $config;
    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $buscarEntidadUrl = "https://glpi.url.net/apirest.php/search/Entity";
    $params = [
            'criteria' =>[
                [
                    'field' => 16,
                    'searchtype' => 'contains',
                    'value' => $nit,
                ]
            ],
            'forcedisplay' => [2]
    ];
    $buscarEntidadUrl .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
    $ch = curl_init($buscarEntidadUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'App-Token: ' . $appToken,
        'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken
    ]);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if($res === false) {
        echo  'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } 
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $data = json_decode($res, true);
    if(!isset($data['data'][0]['2'])){
        echo "no se pudo obtener el id entidad";
        return null;
    }
    $idEntidad = $data['data'][0]['2'];
    return $idEntidad;
}
    
function obtenerUrlImagen($idImagen){
    
    $fbUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/" . $idImagen;
    $ch = curl_init($fbUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: Bearer $token'
    ]);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    if($res === false) {
        echo "Id de la imagen invalido";
        return null;
    }
    
    $data = json_decode($res, true);
    
    if (!isset($data['url'])) {
        echo "URL no encontrada en la respuesta";
        //echo json_encode($data);
        return null;
    }
    $imgUrl = $data['url'];
    return $imgUrl;
}

function subirDocumentoGlpi($ticket, $url, $numero, $nit, $audio = false){
    $glpiUrl = "https://glpi.dwsistemas.net/apirest.php/Document";
    global $config;
    $token = $config['whatsapp-token'];
    $appToken = $config['app-token'];

    $sessionToken = iniciarSesion();
    if (!$sessionToken) {
        echo "Error iniciando sesión en GLPI";
        return;
    }

    $entidad = buscarEntidad($nit, $sessionToken);
    $usuario = buscarUsuario($numero, $sessionToken);

    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => [
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0",
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
            ],
        ]
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $imageData = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if(!$imageData){
        echo 'error al obtener la imagen';
        return;
    }

    if($audio){
        $rutaImagenTemporal = './files/' . uniqid('audio_', true) . '.ogg'; 
    } else {
        $rutaImagenTemporal = './files/' . uniqid('image_', true) . '.jpeg'; 
    }
    
    file_put_contents($rutaImagenTemporal, $imageData);
    $imageFileName = basename($url);

    $mimeType = mime_content_type($rutaImagenTemporal);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $glpiUrl,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
            'App-Token: ' . $appToken,
            'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken,
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
            'uploadManifest' => json_encode([
                'input' => [
                    'name' => 'documento de caso ' . $ticket,
                    'is_private' => 0,
                    'users_id' => $usuario,
                    'entities_id' => $entidad
                ]
            ]),
            'filename[0]' => new CURLFile($rutaImagenTemporal)
        ],
    ]);
    
 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $responseCode;
    curl_close($ch);
    
    
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
    $documentId = $responseData['id'];
        
    asociarDocumentoAlTicket($ticket, $documentId, $sessionToken);
    

    cerrarSesion($sessionToken);
    return $responseData;
}

function asociarDocumentoAlTicket($ticket, $documentId, $sessionToken){
    $glpiUrl = "https://glpi.dwsistemas.net/apirest.php/Ticket/$ticket/Document_Item";
    echo $glpiUrl;
    global $config;

    $appToken = $config['app-token'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    $uploadManifest = [
        'input' => [
            'documents_id' => $documentId,
            'itemtype' => 'Ticket',
            'items_id' => $ticket,
        ]
    ];

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $glpiUrl,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'App-Token: ' . $appToken,
            'Session-Token: ' . $sessionToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($uploadManifest),
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $responseCode;
    curl_close($ch);

    if($responseCode == 200) {
        echo 'ticket asociado correctamente';
    } else {
        echo 'no se pudo asociar el ticket';
    }
}

